# How to fix install shutter in kali linux?

Tags: apt, kali-linux

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install shutter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shutter : Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-vfs-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-wnck-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-gconf-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: perlmagick
           Depends: libproc-simple-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libfile-which-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libsort-naturally-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-imageview-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-unique-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libproc-processtable-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpath-class-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libjson-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libjson-xs-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnet-dropbox-api-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libgoo-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@kali:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ax25-node caribou-antler castxml creepy dff gccxml gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0
  gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gtk2-engines
  gucharmap inguma libasn1-8-heimdal libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavdevice-ffmpeg56
  libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libavutil-ffmpeg54 libax25 libbasicusageenvironment0 libbind9-90
  libboost-atomic1.58.0 libboost-chrono1.58.0 libboost-date-time1.58.0
  libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-python1.58.0 libboost-python1.61.0
  libboost-system1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0 libcamel-1.2-54
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcrypto++9v5 libdbus-1-dev libdns100
  libexporter-tiny-perl libgconf2-4 libgdict-1.0-9 libgif4 libgnome2-0
  libgnome2-bin libgrilo-0.2-1 libgroupsock1 libgssapi3-heimdal libgtkglext1
  libgucharmap-2-90-7 libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhunspell-1.3-0 libhx509-5-heimdal libical1a
  libilmbase6v5 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libjansson4 libjasper1
  libkdc2-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal liblist-moreutils-perl liblivemedia23
  libllvm3.7 liblouis9 liblwres90 libntdb1 libopenexr6v5 libopenjpeg5 libpff1
  libpgm-5.1-0 libpoppler57 libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libpth20
  libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libqmi-glib1 libquvi-scripts
  libquvi7 libregfi0 libroken18-heimdal libsodium13 libstreamanalyzer0v5
  libstreams0v5 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtask-weaken-perl
  libtre5 libtrio2 libusageenvironment1 libusbmuxd2 libuv1 libwebp5
  libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0 libwind0-heimdal
  libwireshark6 libwiretap5 libwsutil6 libx265-68 libyara3 libzip2 libzmq3
  multiforcer oxygen5-icon-theme python-apsw python-bluez
  python-characteristic python-ctypeslib python-dbus-dev python-distlib
  python-dominate python-ecdsa python-flickrapi python-googleapi
  python-instagram python-jwt python-lzma python-lzo python-magic python-ntdb
  python-oauth2client python-oauthlib python-opengl python-pyatspi
  python-pyexiv2 python-pyexiv2-doc python-pyqtgraph python-qt4-gl
  python-qt4-phonon python-requests-oauthlib python-requests-toolbelt
  python-rsa python-tidylib python-tweepy python-uritemplate python-yapsy
  python3.4 python3.4-minimal ratproxy ruby-rainbow ruby-rexec ruby2.2-dev
  system-config-printer
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libart-2.0-2 libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libclass-accessor-perl
  libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
  libcommon-sense-perl libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl
  libdata-random-perl libfile-which-perl libgd-perl libgnome2-canvas-perl
  libgnome2-gconf-perl libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl
  libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common
  libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl libgtkimageview0
  libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl
  libmouse-perl libnet-dropbox-api-perl libnet-oauth-perl libpath-class-perl
  libproc-processtable-perl libproc-simple-perl libsort-naturally-perl
  libtypes-serialiser-perl libunique-1.0-0 libwnck-common libwnck22 perlmagick
Suggested packages:
  imagemagick-doc libmojolicious-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libart-2.0-2 libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libclass-accessor-perl
  libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
  libcommon-sense-perl libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl
  libdata-random-perl libfile-which-perl libgd-perl libgnome2-canvas-perl
  libgnome2-gconf-perl libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl
  libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common
  libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl libgtkimageview0
  libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl
  libmouse-perl libnet-dropbox-api-perl libnet-oauth-perl libpath-class-perl
  libproc-processtable-perl libproc-simple-perl libsort-naturally-perl
  libtypes-serialiser-perl libunique-1.0-0 libwnck-common libwnck22 perlmagick
0 upgraded, 40 newly installed, 0 to remove and 391 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,190 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
apt-listchanges: APT_HOOK_INFO_FD environment variable is incorrectly defined
(Dpkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::InfoFD should be greater than 2).
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10
root@kali:~# /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10
apt-listchanges: APT_HOOK_INFO_FD environment variable is not defined
(is Dpkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::InfoFD set to 20?)
root@kali:~#
```

How can I solve the dependency problem and get shutter installed?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy apt-listchanges`

Comment: root@kali:~# apt-cache policy apt-listchanges
apt-listchanges:
  Installed: 3.3
  Candidate: 3.3
  Version table:
 *** 3.3 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@kali:~#

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could help you out:

```
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges.dpkg-new /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges
apt-get -f install
```

If that doesn't help try rebooting or add this line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges`:

```
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::InfoFD "20";
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: @sukihinata Great! please , do not forget to accept it .